# merge two csv file using python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, csv

i have two csv with common headers i need to merge two csv file into one csv file column wise
my first csv file looks like

```
 step   item    path_of_logfile value
adi landlord    /home/abcd.txt  1000
vc  abcd    /hom/efgh.txt   2000
```

another csv  looks like this

```
step    item    path_of_logfile value
adi landlord    /home/txt        4500
VC  abcd    /home/efgh.txt      3000
DC  abcd    /home/efgh.txt      pass
```

and desired output is

```
step item path_of_logfile value path_of_logfile value
 adi  landlord  /home/abcd.txt 4500 /home/abcd.txt1000
 VC abcd     /home/efgh.txt 3000/home/efgh.txt 2000
 DC   abcd     /home/efgh.txt pass
```

i did through python using pandas

```
code
   import pandas as pd
  first = pd.read_csv('1st.csv')
  second = pd.read_csv('2nd.csv')
  merged = pd.concat([first, second], axis=1)
```

please help me to get desired output csvfile

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  You need to `merge` the data frames instead of concatenating them.  You want to merge on the same key value in this case.

Your problem is a bit more complicated (not much) because your .csv files are not in standard form as you have multiple spaces between values instead of commas (the 'c' in csv).

This works.  Of note, you have a lowercase 'vc' and and upper 'VC' in the other file that don't match.  Perhaps that is a typo?

```
import pandas as pd
first = pd.read_csv('1st.csv', sep= '\s+')
second = pd.read_csv('2nd.csv', sep= '\s+')

merged = first.merge(second, how='outer', on='step')  

print(merged)

merged.to_csv('merged.csv', na_rep='pass', index=False)
```

#### Yields:

```
  step    item_x path_of_logfile_x  value_x    item_y path_of_logfile_y value_y
0  adi  landlord    /home/abcd.txt   1000.0  landlord         /home/txt    4500
1   vc      abcd     /hom/efgh.txt   2000.0       NaN               NaN     NaN
2   VC       NaN               NaN      NaN      abcd    /home/efgh.txt    3000
3   DC       NaN               NaN      NaN      abcd    /home/efgh.txt    pass
```

CSV file:

```
step,item_x,path_of_logfile_x,value_x,item_y,path_of_logfile_y,value_y
adi,landlord,/home/abcd.txt,1000.0,landlord,/home/txt,4500
vc,abcd,/hom/efgh.txt,2000.0,pass,pass,pass
VC,pass,pass,pass,abcd,/home/efgh.txt,3000
DC,pass,pass,pass,abcd,/home/efgh.txt,pass
```

Comment: If your match criteria is both 'step' and 'item' you can pass that in as a list for the `on` field in merge.

Comment: Can we have  another method without using pandas

Comment: sure.  You used pandas in the orig, so it seemed like that was the path you wanted.  You need to update your post with how you want to join the files.  are you just matching "step"?  Also, give it a try with basic reading and dictionaries....

Comment: Can u  provide me the code so that I can use that as a start for my learning

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
first = pd.read_csv('1st.csv', sep='    ', engine='python')
second = pd.read_csv('2nd.csv', sep='    ', engine='python')
merged = pd.concat([second, first] ,axis=1, keys = 'step')
print(merged)
```

Output:

```
s                                    t                                  
  step      item path_of_logfile value step      item path_of_logfile   value
0  adi  landlord       /home/txt  4500  adi  landlord  /home/abcd.txt  1000.0
1   VC      abcd  /home/efgh.txt  3000   vc      abcd   /home/fgh.txt  2000.0
2   DC      abcd  /home/efgh.txt  pass  NaN       NaN             NaN     NaN
```

You need to define the ***keys*** inside ***pd.concat()*** so that it can target the column on which it have to perform the concatenation. Also, i used ***engine='python'*** here otherwise it will throw a warning. I am also considering here that the data here is having 4 space separator that's why i have assigned 4 spaces to ***sep*** method.

Comment: Can we do without using pandas

Comment: @humblefool78 i do not see any other method to perform the concatenation because dataframe is still needed to operate concatenation, however i do not know if there is any other method or not and if there is one then it will be great to learn that new method